# Concurrency issue when 2 users enter the room at the same time

Tags: ios, swift

I have a group video chat app I am working on at the moment, when a user clicks a 'join room' button it moves him into a room.
In a room there are several fields, one of them is 'availablePositions'([Bool]: false means available position, true means occupied position), when a user joins a room, I update the room on the server side so that the available position that the user just occupied will become occupied, and I also do that on the client side.
Everything works fine when users are joining the same room at a slight delay from one another, but when 2 users click 'join room' at the same time, only 1 position gets occupied as my program treats it as a single user.

I was able to track down the problem, sending the data to the server so the positions will update happens for both users at a similar time so they are both unaware of each other. (I fetch the positions from the DB before updating the positions, but in this case, fetching the positions at the same time yields the same results, and what I need to happen is that 1 user will send data, and only after successfully posting to server, user 2 will fetch positions and send its own data, and so on..)

When a user enters the room I call this function:

```
private func findEmptyPosition() -> Int? {
        guard let room = room else {return nil}
        for (i,isOccupied) in room.availablePositions.enumerated() {
            if isOccupied {
                continue
            }
            return i
        }
        return nil
    }
```

The function above returns i which is '0' in a new room, for both users.

Then I call this function with the return result of the fn above, to update the DB:

```
private func updateAvailablePositions(withIndex i:Int, isOccupying:Bool) {

    guard let room = room else {return}
    
    networkManager.fetchData(type: [RoomModel].self, url: networkManager.roomsURL) { rooms in
        for currentRoom in rooms {
            if currentRoom.id == self.room?.id {
                room.availablePositions = currentRoom.availablePositions
            }
        }
        room.availablePositions[i] = isOccupying
        self.networkManager.sendData(object: room, url: self.networkManager.roomsURL, httpMethod: Constants.HttpMethods.PUT.rawValue) { response in
            print("PUT response: \(response)")
        }
    }
}
```

Also, before I call any of these functions, I present a loading screen, to search for an available room. these are the functions I call before entering a room.

Main function to find empty room:

```
private func findEmptyRoom() {
    guard let category = self.categoryLabel.text else {return}
    networkManager.fetchData(type: [RoomModel].self, url: networkManager.roomsURL) { [weak self] results in
        let relevantRooms = results.filter { $0.category.makeComparable() == category.makeComparable() }
        if let emptyRoom = self?.searchFirstEmpty(results: relevantRooms) {
            self?.moveToRoom(withRoom: emptyRoom)
        } else {
            self?.createEmptyRoom(withCategory:category)
        }
    }
}
```

functions that build that function:

```
    private func moveToRoom(withRoom room:RoomModel) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let roomVC = RoomViewController()
        roomVC.title = room.category
        roomVC.room = room
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(roomVC, animated: true)
    }
}

private func searchFirstEmpty(results:[RoomModel]) -> RoomModel? {
    var emptyPositionIX = -1
    for room in results {
        for i in 0..<room.availablePositions.count {
            if (!room.availablePositions[i]) {
                emptyPositionIX = i
                break
            }
        }
        if (emptyPositionIX > -1) {
            return room
        }
    }
    return nil
}

private func createEmptyRoom(withCategory category:String) {
    let newRoom = RoomModel(id: UUID(), category: category)
    networkManager.sendData(object: newRoom, url: networkManager.roomsURL, httpMethod: Constants.HttpMethods.POST.rawValue)
    { [weak self] response in
        print("POST response: \(response)")
        self?.moveToRoom(withRoom: newRoom)
    }
}
```

Hope I've made it clear, thanks.

Comment: This is a textbook example of a race condition. How you make this an atomic action (either the entire operation succeeds or fails together) depends on how your backend is implemented. What kind of server stores this database? If possible, the easiest answer is to just send a "join" request to the server, and let the server decide where to put you in the roster.

Comment: @RobNapier I've implemented my own Vapor server, I will look into letting the server decide the positions instead of just storing them.
also, thanks for the lovely insight, now that I know this is a known concept of concurrent programming, it will be much easier to find information on how to approach it.

Comment: The other term you can search for is "data race" which is the specific situation you're encountering. Best of luck!

Comment: @RobNapier I managed to solve it with your advice on moving the responsibility to the server.  Thank you very much!